# Dokan vendor's personal store page not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, dokan

I’m creating a multi vendor website with free version of Dokan and Woocommerce. The links of vendor’s personal store pages don’t seem to be working. When I type the URL or try clicking the button on store list to go to their personal store page I just get redirected to the websites landing page. I already checked my permalinks and everything and I have no idea what could possibly be wrong. Please help!
[image]

Comment: I think that nobody here can guess that by magic, better ask Dokan support directly as stack overflow is mostly code oriented.